# Is there a way of transporting a pickle file of machine learning written in python (scikit-learn) into node.js?

Tags: node.js, rest, scikit-learn, pickle, transpiler

I would like to use python just for creating machine learning models and then transporting them onto the web using JS. I've done a simple project similar to this, but I used Flask for simple backend/API.
I'm also okay with creating APIs in Flask or Django, and then doing backend in Node.js, if that is possible. I've never done backend before, and my knowledge of frontend and ml is on beginner level.

 I would like to build a good and scalable web application that uses ml for It's calculations.

 I would like to use Bootstrap for looks, JS for both frontend (React) and backend (Node.js), and Python (Scikit-learn) for machine learning algorithms.

 Any suggestions of file structure, organization and which libraries and programming languages I should use are welcome. You can checkout my code and app in links. It isn't anything special, but it works, and I want to build on it.

 http://alumil-alloys.herokuapp.com/

https://github.com/nemanjaKostovski/MLmodel

 PS what I especially don't like about my app is Flask affecting the frontend. I don't like my html markings for displaying answer.